# A proposition in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Problem: Let $A$ and $B$ be C*-algebra and $\varphi:A \rightarrow B$ be a contractive completely positive map. $A_{\varphi}=\{a\in A: \varphi(a^{\ast}a)=\varphi(a)^{\ast}\varphi(a)$ and $\varphi(aa^{\ast})=\varphi(a)\varphi(a)^{\ast}\}$, how to proof $A_{\varphi}$ is self-adjoint (i.e., if $a\in A_{\varphi}$, then $a^{\ast} \in A_{\varphi}$).

There is only word in the proof of this proposition: Following from the Bimodule property, that is, Given $a\in A$, if $\varphi(a^{\ast}a)=\varphi(a)^{\ast}\varphi(a)$ and $\varphi(aa^{\ast})=\varphi(a)\varphi(a)^{\ast}$, then $\varphi(ba)=\varphi(b)\varphi(a)$ and $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$.

I do not know how to use the Bimodule property. Could someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows just from the definition and the fact that $\varphi$ is $*$-preserving: if $a\in A_\varphi$, then 
$$
\varphi((a^*)^*a^*)=\varphi(aa^*)=\varphi(a)\varphi(a^*)=\varphi(a^*)^*\varphi(a^*). 
$$

Comment: A contractive completely positive map is ∗-preserving?

Comment: Of course. Any positive linear map is $*$-preserving: $$\phi(a)^*=\phi(\text{Re}\,a+i\,\text{Im}\, a)^*=[\phi(\text{Re}\,a)+i\,\phi(\text{Im}\, a)]^*=\phi(\text{Re}\,a)-i\,\phi(\text{Im}\, a)=\phi(\text{Re}\,a-i\,\text{Im}\, a)=\phi(a^*) $$ (as $\phi$ is positive, it maps selfadjoints to selfadjoints).

Comment: May I use Stinespring Dilation to show that completely positive map is a *-preserving ? Because $\phi(a^{\ast})=(V^{\ast}π(a)V)^{\ast}=\phi(a)^{\ast}$. Here, π is a *- representation.

Comment: And does the $A_{\phi}$ is the largest algebra in A? why?

Comment: I don't think you can prove Stinespring (as far as I know) without using that $\phi$ is $*$-preserving. Besides, the assertion holds for all positive linear maps, not just the completely positive ones.

Comment: $A_\phi$ is the multiplicative domain. I don't know what you mean by "largest" here.

Comment: :Sorry, I mean that $A_{\phi}$ is the largest subalgebra of $A$ on which $\phi$ restricts to a *-homomorphism. And as your proof above, we can also conclude that if $\phi$ is selfadjiont, then $\phi$ is *-preserving.

Comment: Yes, it is. That's because $A_\phi=\{b\in A:\ \phi(ba)=\phi(b)\phi(a),\ \phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)\,\forall a\in A\}$.

Comment: @Martin Argerami,Pro Argerami,$\phi(a)^*=\phi(\text{Re}\,a+i\,\text{Im}\,a)^*=[\phi(\text{Re}\,a)+i\,\phi(\text{Im}\, a)]^*=\phi(\text{Re}\,a)-i\,\phi(\text{Im}\, ,a)=\phi(\text{Re}\,a-i\,\text{Im}\,a)=\phi(a^*)$,   why the third equality hold?

Comment: Because (as it says in my comment) $\phi $ maps selfadjoints to selfadjoints.